# Check for expired account for users created by adminCreateUser in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have a Lambda function which creates users using `adminCreateUser` Cognito function. My app is basically an invite only app where the admin can only invite certain users. Everything is working great so far, and I am able to resend invitation email notifications as well. However, I am trying to figure out how I can find out if a user created by `adminCreateUser` method has "expired" i.e. the user has not accepted the invite and changed the temporary password.

When the admin creates a user using `adminCreateUser` the status is `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD` by default. When the user with this status attempts to Log in using the temporary password (from the verification email), Cognito sends a challenge back in the `challengeName` attribute of `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED`, based on which the user is forced to change their password through the application and upon successful reset the status would change to `CONFIRMED` in Cognito for that user. This is working great so far, but I also need to handle scenario where the invited user never really changed their password by attempting to log into the application.

Now, I have set the - *"**How quickly should user accounts created by administrators expire if not used?**"* - to 7 days (default). What would be the status of the user account after 7 days if the user doesn't reset their password? I tried to find out from the documentation but it's not clear what the status of the user account would be in this situation.

**NOTE:** This is not about Token expiration in the client but rather expiration of an account created via the `adminCreateUser` method.

Answer (score -2):

Annjawn,

According below link: "After the account expires, the user cannot log in to the account until the administrator updates the user's profile by updating an attribute or by resending the password to the user"

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-admin-create-user-policy.html

All tthe best,

Guto